# Should accepted answers be pinned to the top on meta?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, meta

<sub>most of the text in this answer has been taken from [another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568)</sub>

There's [a proposal on main Meta regarding accepted answers floating to the top in the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568). I'll selectively quote parts of CM Nicolas Chabanovsky's question here to get you up to speed with the specifics of the discussion:

> Today we changed the way we sort answers on Stack Overflow. We no longer pin the accepted answer (with the green checkmark) to the top of the list of answers. By default, we now sort strictly by votes (descending order by highest score), and the accepted answer's order in the list is based on its score.

> We can change the way the engine sorts answers in site settings. We would like to hear from you all if it is something you want to see on your site. (Please let me acknowledge in advance that we will not be able to run a test on each site.)

> Please let us know what you think will work best for your site! If you can discuss this question with your community it would be awesome. We are going to collect feedback before the end of September 19th.

How does the Politics meta community feel about accepted answers floating to the top? Should we follow Stack Overflow's lead of sorting by answer score only?

Feel free to use the answer box here to share specific concerns about answer sorting on Politics meta. If you want to discuss specifics about the new way of answer sorting then it's probably best to reply to [Nicolas' question on main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568).

[Answer showing main site and meta site different for Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914/560258)

Note: it is possible for a meta site to have different rules on unpinning then a main site, cause Ask Ubuntu has that.

Comment: I thought pining and unpinning was the same for the main and meta site and we already have unpinned answsers.

Comment: @JoeW [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914/560258) to the main meta question mentions that ask Ubuntu meta had a discussion about this, so I figured that if you wanted it to be different from the main site it could be.

Comment: You should put that in your question and include a link to that. I had read that question and was under the impression that both main and meta site would get the same treatment on the pin or unpin question. It would have saved time if I could have seen from your question that there was already precedent for the main site unpinning and the meta site keeping the pin.

Comment: @JoeW completed

Comment: I added in a link to that answer so people can see where it was from. Also would it be possible to remove two of the links to the question? I find it a bit confusing to have 3 links to the same place when only a single one is needed.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to say no to this as I think the reason for unpinning the accepted answer applies to the meta site just as it applies to the main site. Overall I don't think there are going to be many cases where the accepted answer is not the highest scoring one. In those cases I think we will end up confusing users if they see different behavior on the main and meta sites and we will end up having to explain it to them.